# AngularJS: filter repeat match against list

Tags: angularjs, loops, filter, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have a list of objects that gets looped over by ngRepeat:

```
hashes = [
  {
      "type": "foo"
    , …
  }
  , {
      "type": "foo"
    , …
  }
  , {
      "type": "bar"
    , …
  }
]
```

I want to filter them based on `type` if it's value matches a item in a list of needles:

```
types = ['foo','quz'];
```

so something like

```
<div ng-repeat="hash in hashes | filter:types"></div>
```

Is this built into Angular or would I have to write a custom filter?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

To filter against a single type you can do:

```
<div ng-repeat="hash in hashes | filter: {type:'foo'}">
```

To filter against an array you don't need a completely custom filter but I would use a predicate filter that you can pass in to Angular's filter.  Here's the filter, assuming your array `type`:

```
$scope.filterArray = function(hash) {
    return ($scope.types.indexOf(hash.type) !== -1);
};
```

Used like this:

```
<div ng-repeat="hash in hashes | filter: filterArray">
```

[demo fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hF9fN/3/) of both

**Custom Filter**

To do a completely custom filter, this works:

```
filter('inArray', function() {
    return function inArray( haystack , needle ) {
        var result = [];
        var item,i;
        for (i=0; i< haystack.length;i++) {
            item = haystack[i];
            if (needle.indexOf(item.type) !== -1)
              result.push(item);
        };
        return (result);
    };
});
```

Used like this:

```
<div ng-repeat="hash in hashes | inArray: types">
```

[demo of custom filter](http://jsfiddle.net/hF9fN/5/)

Comment: I ended up making it a proper filter called `inArray` (&agrave; la php's in_array). Added it to the bottom of my question.

Comment: @jacob are you sure that filter is working correctly for you?  Generally a custom filter wants an array of all the values that pass to be returned (unlike the predicate filter which is done on a per entry basis)- but it appears you're returning a boolean.

Comment: Ah that explains why *needle* is the entire array that was passed to ngRepeat instead of the property I specified. [SO:21344961](http://stackoverflow.com/q/21344961/758177)

Comment: can we use this filter with a particular attribute of the collection?